# Google web font causes Safari crash

Tags: html, css, google-webfonts

My app has been crashing on Safari (only) and I've narrowed it down to this one line:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,500,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

This line causes no issue if I only load one weight, but once I add a second, Safari crashes again.  In other words, the following works:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

... this also works

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Are other browsers actually loading the additional weights? If not they might just be failing more gracefully. Wondering if it might be an issue with one of the files Google is serving up.

Comment: Apparently it's a known issue that applies to the Quicksand font: https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/2155